# How to sql-sync database between two remotes which share the same host?

Tags: deployment, drush

I've two remotes: `@source` and `@destination`.

I'm trying to transfer the database from dev to test environment by using `sql-sync`:

```
$ drush -vy sql-sync @source @destination
```

But at the end drush complains that:

> The source and destination cannot both be remote.
>
> rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1166) [Receiver=3.0.9]

Both remotes are on the same machine, but they're using different path.

I'm using latest drush 7.0-dev.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how drush sql-sync works between two remotes:

1. Logs into remote `@destination` via SSH and creates destination database if needed via `sql-create`.
2. Backs up database on `@source`by performing `sql-dump` on source unless told otherwise and saves it into `drush-backups` folder.
3. Logs into `@destination` remote via SSH and executes `rsync` to transfer database from Source to Destination.

   Example: `rsync @source:drush-backups/db.sql.gz @destination:/tmp/db.sql.gz`

To make this work, you have to make sure that:

- both local and remote drush have the same version (either 6.x or 7.x),
- on Destination the `@source` alias should be accessible for drush,
- `rsync` tool doesn't support two remotes, so only one may be remote.

Based on above it seems you can't use `sql-sync` drush command to transfer the database between two remotes in drush 7.x (see: [#161](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/161)).

As for workaround, first dump the database from your source onto your local and transfer back to the destination, in example:

```
drush @source sql-dump | drush @destination sql-cli
```

This should transfer the database between two remotes without `sql-sync` limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Another option I use is to use drush ssh command to execute drush on the source :

```
drush @source ssh "drush sql-sync @self @destination"
```

Comment: This got drush 9 working for me. Also works:

`drush @dest ssh "drush sql-sync @source @self"`